# CFNetwork WebCore Crash

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

I'm getting some crash reports from the App Store that I can't really follow. So the thread always crash like this

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib    
objc_msgSend + 15
1    CFNetwork ✭    
HostBase::lock() + 14
2    CFNetwork  
DispatchHost::performInvocation(void const*) + 12
3    CFNetwork  
__setupTCPConnection_block_invoke_2 + 290
4
...
libsystem_network.dylib 
__tcp_connection_notify_complete_block_invoke_1 + 18
5    libdispatch.dylib  
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6    libdispatch.dylib  
_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 258
7    libsystem_c.dylib  
_pthread_wqthread + 294
```

I have like 14 of these crashes. The only thing they have in common is this other thread.

```
...
libsystem_kernel.dylib  
mach_msg_trap + 20
1    CoreFoundation 
__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2    CoreFoundation 
__CFRunLoopRun + 882
3    CoreFoundation 
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4    CoreFoundation 
CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5    WebCore    
WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 128
6    libsystem_c.dylib  
_pthread_start + 320
```

I use UIWebViews in my app (although not intensively. IS WebCore only called when using webViews? Or can this be relted to something else?

I can't replicate in my device. Any idea will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: you don't have to look what they have in common but which Thread crashed. Important snippets are `Crashed Thread:`, `Exception Type:` and the whole stack of the crashed Thread. can you update your question with that information please? (best if you add the whole crash report)

Answer (score 0):

Got same stackstrace in our app, and talked about in the devforums : https://devforums.apple.com/message/683938#683938

And it lead to the conclusion :

> I can't see anything of interest here, leading me back to the conclusion that this is either some sort of memory corruption issue in your app or a bug in CFNetwork (and both are quite likely possibilities).

So I tracked and fixed some memory leaks in the app, then I'll see if the crash still occurs in next app release.

Comment: Hmmm... how could a memory leak cause that? Maybe an overrelease, but a leak?

Comment: You are right, I've checked all release/retain of objects that are using `NSURLConnection` or `UIWebView`. And after a release, I set these ones to nil to be sure I don't overrelease them.

Answer (score 0):

Since your use of UIWebViews is not extensive, it could be a good idea to investigate if all UIWebView operations are being made on the main UI thread. You could you be on a background thread while loading a request or setting the data on the UIWebView.

Comment: If I see WebCore code, are we possitive it is related to UIWebViews?